# Proxying a Java class with an internal class cast

Tags: java, proxy

Here's a problem I am facing.

I am writing a plugin. There is an interface called *SystemObject*, and a default getter.

```
public class MyPlugin extends Plugin {
        @override
        public SystemObject getSystemObject() {
                return super.getSystemObject();
        } 
}
```

SystemObject interface has a method called getScreenSize() which I would like to proxy or intercept. When I create a proxy class, or simply implement this SystemObject interface myself, I get a class cast exception.

This is because the caller for getSystemObject (part of the plugin system) has this in their code (found via reverse-engineering):

```
private void foo() { 
     SystemObjectImpl impl = (SystemObjectImpl)plugin.getSystemObject(); 
}
```

---

My question is: **is there any way I can proxy calls on the SystemObject interface?**

I tried implementing the interface and using java reflection proxy invocation to no avail. Unfortunately, I'm not responsible for running the java process, so I can't use an agent.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net) to create a proxy class that extends `SystemObjectImpl`.

Comment: but it creates a new instance, right? what if the caller in foo() uses private members set in the original instance?

Comment: It seems like a design flaw in the plugin system if it makes it possible for you to provide a custom implementation of the `SystemObject` interface but then depends internally on the default implementation... All you can do is try it and see what happens.  The point I was trying to make is simply that CGLIB would let you create a proxy object that is an `instanceof SystemObjectImpl`, so that the cast in `foo()` doesn't fail.

Comment: true. it's a very bad design. I couldn't find another solution. thank you for your answer!